# Calling SQL procedure from Zend PHP gives @@@@@ as result

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework, procedure

I have recently loaded Zend Server on my iSeries and am trying to run an SQL stored procedure.  When I run a regular SQL query everything works.

When I change the query to the SQL stored procedure everything looks like it runs but the result is "@"s.

I set my out variable to " " and after the called procedure runs the variable is 26 "@" which is the length of my field in DB2.  What would cause regular SQL to work but stored SQL procedures to give this result?

I changed system value QCCSID from 65355 to 37 and that didn't help.

Comment: Do you have correct character set and/or collation? `@` can be replacement for character w/o equivalent in target character set?